# Empty files when exporting to Excel in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I have a page that allows the user to pick a staff member and a date range(from and to). They can then filter records based on that. I want to have the option to export the data to an Excel format but when I click export, it downloads a blank spreadsheet. Can anyone please help me find my problem here.

Controller:

```
public function exportvehicles(Request $request)
{
    $startDate = $request->startDate;
    $endDate = $request->endDate;


    return Excel::download(new ExportV($startDate, $endDate), 'excelname.xlsx');
}
```

Model:

```
class ExportV implements FromQuery
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
   
    use Exportable;

    protected $startDate;
    protected $endDate;

    function __construct($startDate,$endDate) {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        $startDate = request()->input('startDate', '2021-01-01');
        $endDate = request()->input('endDate', '2021-12-12');
        $data = VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
        ->join('smsstaff', 'vehicleslog.smsstaff_key', '=', 'smsstaff.smsstaff_key')
        ->when(request()->input('smsstaff_key'), function ($query) {
            $query->where('smsstaff.smsstaff_key', request()->input('smsstaff_key'));
        })
        ->whereDate('log_dt', '>=', $startDate)
        ->whereDate('log_dt', '<=', $endDate)
        ->get();

        return $data;
    }

}
```

View:

```
   <label>Pick a staff member</label>
    <select name="smsstaff_key" id="smsstaff_key">
        <option>----------------Select-----------------</option>
        @foreach ($staff as $staffMember) 
           <option value="{{$staffMember->smsstaff_key}}" {{request()->input('smsstaff_key') === $staffMember->smsstaff_key ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>{{$staffMember->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
   </select>
   <button  class="btn btn-primary">Filter by selected staff member</button>
  
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 100px;">
    <label>From:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="startDate" value="{{ $startDate }}">
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 150px;">
    <label>To:</label>
    <input style="width: 14em" type="date" class="form-control" name="endDate" value="{{ $endDate }}">
</div>
<a href="{{"/users/export/"}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Export to Excel</a>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('users/export/', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ReportController@exportvehicles');
```

Comment: if you do a toSql on your query, do you get results from your database?

Comment: @Thomas Okay I removed the `get()` and it exports but it exports all the records. Any way to get it to export just the filtered ones?

Comment: Try to submit your input as form. Filtering is not working because you are submitting the inputs into application

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai How would I do that?

Comment: can you post the route code for the export operation ?

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai I have edited the question to show it

Comment: Posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

When you need to send the values to server to need to submit that as form.

```
//web.php
Route::post('users/export/', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ReportController@exportvehicles')->name('exportVehiclesToExcel');
```

View:

```
<form action="{{route('exportVehiclesToExcel')}}" method="POST">
    <label>Pick a staff member</label>
    <select name="smsstaff_key" id="smsstaff_key">
        <option>----------------Select-----------------</option>
        @foreach ($staff as $staffMember)
        <option value="{{$staffMember->smsstaff_key}}" {{request()->input('smsstaff_key') === $staffMember->smsstaff_key ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>{{$staffMember->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Filter by selected staff member</button>

    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 100px;">
        <label>From:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="startDate" value="{{ $startDate }}">
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 150px;">
        <label>To:</label>
        <input style="width: 14em" type="date" class="form-control" name="endDate" value="{{ $endDate }}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Export to Excel</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function exportvehicles(Request $request)
{

$startDate = $request->startDate;
$endDate = $request->endDate;
$smsStaffKey = $request->smsstaff_key


return Excel::download(new ExportV($startDate, $endDate, $smsStaffKey), 'excelname.xlsx');
}
```

Excel Export Class

```
class ExportV implements FromQuery
{

    use Exportable;

    public $startDate;
    public $endDate;
    public $smsStaffKey;

    function __construct($startDate, $endDate, $smsStaffKey = null)
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
        $this->smsStaffKey = $smsStaffKey;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        $startDate = $this->startDate;
        $endDate = $this->endDate;
        $data = VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
        ->join('smsstaff', 'vehicleslog.smsstaff_key', '=', 'smsstaff.smsstaff_key')
        ->when($this->smsStaffKey, function ($query) {
            $query->where('smsstaff.smsstaff_key', $this->smsStaffKey);
        })
            ->whereDate('log_dt', '>=', $startDate)
            ->whereDate('log_dt', '<=', $endDate);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment if there is any issues

Comment: it says `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`. Any idea why?

Comment: updated my code in routes